# Error: Segmentation fault using fopen and open

Tags: c

I'm connecting a BeagleBoneBlack with a IMU using I2C protocol. I already read data in console great but when im trying to store data in a .txt file, it return me error: Segmentation fault.

```
int I2C_open()
{
    int file;
    char *dev = "/dev/i2c-1";
    if ((file=open(dev,O_RDWR))<0);
    {
        perror("Abrir el canal");
    }
    return file;
}

int main()
{
    archivo=I2C_open();
    f=fopen("./home/debian/Desktop/Comunicacion/Prueba.txt","W");
    fprintf(f,"Datos leidos del sensor");
}
```

This is just part of the code because it's large. The problem is presented when i use the fprintf, when i commented that line the code run well. Im not sure if is because im using fopen while "/dev/i2c-1" is running. Please help

Comment: Did you include the proper header files? What does `gcc` say when `-Wall` is passed to it? Where does the error occur when you run `strace` against it?

Comment: The filename in `fopen()` is relative path. Does the path exist? Did you check if `fopen()` returns non-NULL file desc?

Comment: I just checked and 'fopen()' returns a NULL file. My header fies are '#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>'

Comment: `fopen()` return `NULL` because it can't create file in inexistent directory. Use full path instead of relative path in specifying file. Or don't specify a path and file will be created in current working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:  You used `"W"` instead of `"w"` as the open mode to fopen.  That's the real problem.

But, you should always check the "f" variable for NULL after the fopen.  I'm fairly sure that it's NULL [which means you couldn't open the file].  This is just good practice.  It's much easier than tracking down a segfault.

You have:

```
f=fopen("./home/debian/Desktop/Comunicacion/Prueba.txt","W");
fprintf(f,"Datos leidos del sensor");
```

Change this to:

```
f=fopen("./home/debian/Desktop/Comunicacion/Prueba.txt","w");
if (f == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
}
fprintf(f,"Datos leidos del sensor");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed out the file pointer from the `fprintf` statement

```
fprintf("Datos leidos del sensor");
```

Try

```
fprintf(f, "Datos leidos del sensor");
```

Comment: No sorry i im using    fprintf(f,"Datos leidos del sensor") and i have that problema the error was not that.

Comment: @Juan Bravo so that's NOT your code? OK since the `fprintf` is your problem, why don't you check `f` returned by `fopen()`?

Comment: I wrote my code with fprintf(f,"Datos del sensor"). when I was writing the question I did not write well but in my code the function is written as you say

Comment: @Juan Bravo so what about adding `if((f=fopen("./home/debian/Desktop/Comunicacion/Prueba.txt","W")) == NULL) exit(1);` for example ? My point is you are having problems with `fprintf`, is this the ACTUAL CODE YOU WROTE or are you a time waster?

Comment: How can I check if 'f' returned by 'fopen()1 is correct? @Weather Vane

Comment: By checking `f == NULL` as I just wrote in my above comment.

Comment: It appear this message: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit'. What it mean? @Weather Vane

Comment: @Juan Bravo OK, instead of that, after the line `f=fopen(...);` add `if(f==NULL) {printf("Failed to open file\n"); return 1;}

Comment: Yes the problem is with 'f'. But im using 'f=fopen("./home/debian/Desktop/Comunicacion/Prueba.txt","W");' what is wrong? I tried to used `if(f==NULL) {perror("Error");}' and it say Error: Invalid argument @Weather Vane

Comment: @Juan Bravo try changing "W" to "w" (lower case).

Comment: No it doesn't work but i have another clue, when i change the order of 'archivo=I2C_open();' and 'f=fopen("./home/debian/Desktop/Comunicacion/Prueba.txt","W");' now 'archivo' is the problem no 'f'. I think is something with the order I open the files. @Weather Vane

Comment: Are you sure you want relative path? Not absolute path? `"/home/..."`